# Simulating key event press, forces hold down on down arrow?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events

I'm doing a pretty basic challenge of beating the Chrome dino game with a simple JS script. You can find it either at chrome://dino/ or https://chromedino.com/
My jump/cactus event dispatching works fine, but my "duck" holds down and doesn't just press and I have no idea how to debug/find out why its holding down rather than just pressing.

Any help would be appreciated, this is only a small simple project, nothing serious

```
// A JS script made for the offline Chrome dino game. Accessible from either chrome://dino/ or https://chromedino.com/ 
var canvas   = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0],
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");          // Return the drawing context of the canvas 

(function recurse(){
// Reduce the Uint8ClampedArray into a number. If it isn't zero, there's an obstacle
// This is the cactus jump
let cactus      = (ctx.getImageData(85,118,60,1).data).reduce(reducer); 
// This is the duck, when the Pterodactyl comes 
let pterodactyl = (ctx.getImageData(90,85,1,1   ).data).reduce(reducer);
if(cactus){ 
    var e = new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'keyCode':38,'which':38});
    document.dispatchEvent(e);
    console.log(cactus)
} else if(pterodactyl){
    var e = new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'keyCode':40,'which':40});
    document.dispatchEvent(e);
}
setTimeout(recurse, 50);
})();

function reducer(a,b){
    return a + b
}
```

I have checked that the keyboard event isn't firing `KeyboardEvent.repeat` from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent and it isn't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then maybe try `keypress` instead of `keydown`

So why jump is fine?
Idk what your `jump` is but my bet is that `jump` action cant be held down unlike `duck` where you duck as long as key is pressed down

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the idea but `keypress` didn't work either

Comment: What if you trigger `keyup` event after thr event to dispacth command `duck` is fired? Does it still ducking or not?